# Font awesome on a Mac, awful on a PC

Tags: html, css, fonts

I choose for my website the following font:

http://fontscore.com/fonts/Helvetica-Neue-LT-Std-35-Thin_22514.html

On a Mac this font looks awesome while on Windows it looks horrible. Here's the screenshots:

[image: This is on a mac]

[image: And this is on a pc]

I tried to convert the font using a [fontgenerator](http://convertfonts.com/); I also add this stuff:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

Still the same result. I know that windows use Cleartype and treat fonts in different manner with respect to a Mac but is it possible to solve this?

EDIT:
Here's my font face rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Thin';
    src: url('fonts/helvetica-neue-lt.eot');
    src: url('fonts/helvetica-neue-lt.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/helvetica-neue-lt.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/helvetica-neue-lt.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/helvetica-neue-lt.svg#Thin') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using on your PC?

Comment: can you post your full `@font-face` code?

Comment: helvetica neue lt ... ein ? Is this question a scam ? Don't use that font. The net is filled with infos about the 'helvetica neue' freakshow bug ... https://www.google.ca/#q=don't+use+helvetica+neue+on+website

Comment: What version of IE / chrome / firefox are you using on the PC? Does it  happen for all those browsers or just IE? Do you for some reason have a height to the links with overflow hidden applied?

Comment: This is happening on firefox and chrome. On IE does not even recognize it and just render text in times new roman.

Comment: No this question is not a scam. I just look over the web for a nice free font and this fits perfectly.. on a mac..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HelveticaNeue is an Apple system font. I don't believe there is a PC equivalent, asside Helvetica, witch is not the same, but a close looking one.

We had this situation too, especialy after trying to work with zurbFondation. We tried to debug, even wrote to mozilla ..

My best solution to your problem : **don't use helvetica neue** and stop your designers from using them like those who know not much about rendering engines.

Just **don't use it**. If you really really need explanations about 'why not use it' do like us, spend about 6 hours testing cross-plateform, cross-browsers .. and another 4 hours arguing with technical director and designers.

Yeah, this answer is not much of 'scientific' buy AYE! believe me, it's bad.

https://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&q=helvetica+neue+pc+firefox+problem

https://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&q=helvetica+neue+pc+problem

https://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&q=helvetica+neue+problem

Comment: I read also about that. Ok I think I learn my lesson: "do not go out the standard in web programming". I think I will use arial and that's it :)

Comment: No, i mean, you should NOT avoid web-fonts. The 'helveticaNeue' font itself presents browser-rendering situations 'mac - pc - unix', but there are good forges, google-fonts gives a good web-font stack. There are some for you, better looking than plain Arial.

Answer (score 1):

HelveticaNeue is a Mac system font, and the exact version that Apple uses is not available on PC (as far as I know). I usually add 'Arial' to the font-family style, and it displays fine on a PC.

Comment: Probably the right answer, but I believe Helvetica is closer, and it degrades to Arial if you include both in the font-family style.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using http://www.google.com/fonts/

Arimo is a compatible font for helevetica neue

easy to implement and compatible across all platforms

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article from typekit: [CSS properties that affect type rendering](http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/26/css-properties-that-affect-type-rendering/) .

Quoted from this article:

> When it comes to type rendering on the web, there’s not much web designers can do. The way fonts appear on screen is mostly due to operating systems, browsers, typeface designs, font files, and how those font files are (or are not) augmented with instructions for the most unforgiving rendering scenarios. But in some cases, CSS properties can affect how type looks.

It's from 2011, but it covers some interesting things about font rendering which are still useful.